# How do I revert the html content to its original value?

Tags: jquery

After a user presses a key in the div the html is set to " ". However, after the user has left the div I would like to set the html back to it's original value. How can I do that?

I have the following code so far:

```
$(document).one('keypress',"#id",function() { 
        $(this).html("");
    }).focusout(function(){
        //do something 
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cache it in the element itself using `.data()`:

```
$(document).one('keypress',"#id",function() { 
    $(this).data('html',$(this).html()).html('');
}).focusout(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).data('html'));
});
```

I prefer this approach because by storing the data on `this`, it works with any selector, including those that match multiple DOM elements. You just need to be sure the `data()` variable (`'html'` here) isn't being used by any other code on the page.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
(function()
{
    var html = null;
    $(document).one('keypress',"#id",function() { 
        html = $(this).html();
        $(this).html("");
    }).focusout(function(){
        //do something 
        $(this).html(html);
    });
})();
```

I've wrapped it in a self executing anonymous function so that you keep the `html` variable out of the main scope.

Or in a more jQuery way:

```
$(document).one('keypress',"#id",function() { 
    $(this).data('orightml', $(this).html());
    $(this).html("");
}).focusout(function(){
    //do something 
    $(this).html($(this).data('orightml'));
});
```

This way we're storing the original html against the element.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
var orig;
$(document).one('keypress',"#id",function() { 
        orig = $(this).html();
        $(this).html("");
    }).focusout(function(){
        //do something 
        $(this).html(orig);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the value in a a variable so you can recover it after the focus out.

```
var divValue;
$(document).one('keypress',"#id",function() { 
    divValue = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("");
}).focusout(function(){
    $(this).html(divValue);
});
```